# @media rule not turning off when screen gets larger

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I have the following in my CSS file, and it works fine apart from the rule around `--md` and `--sm` arent turning off when the screen width goes over 899px.

```
.ProductThumbnail {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    &--md,
    &--sm {

      display: none;
      background-position: 30% top;

      @include media('sm', true, true) {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    &--lg {

      display: none;
      background-position: 25% top;
      width: 1600px;

      @include media('md', true) {
        display: block;
      }
    }
}
```

The return function in the react component is as follows:

```
return (
  <>
    <div
      className="ProductThumbnail__bg ProductThumbnail__bg--xs"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: getURL({
          w: 600,
          h: 455,
        }),
      }}
    />
    <div
      className="ProductThumbnail__bg ProductThumbnail__bg--md"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: getURL({
          h: 455,
        }),
      }}
    />
    <div
      className="ProductThumbnail__bg ProductThumbnail__bg--lg"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: getURL({
          w: 2560,
          h: 1040,
        }),
      }}
    />
  </>
);
```

I can see in the dev tools that the rules are being applied as expected for `--md` and `--sm` but they dont disappear when the screen gets bigger.

Update, media mixin code:

```
@mixin media(
  $breakpoint,
  $is-minimum-only: false,
  $is-maximum-only: false) {

  @if map_has_key($breakpoint-ranges, $breakpoint) {
    $breakpoint-range: get-break-point-range($breakpoint);
    $breakpoint: "";

    @if length($breakpoint-range) < 2 or $is-minimum-only {
      $breakpoint: "(min-width:#{nth($breakpoint-range, 1)})";
    } @else if $is-maximum-only {
      $breakpoint: "(max-width:#{nth($breakpoint-range, 2)})";
    } @else {
      $breakpoint: "(min-width:#{nth($breakpoint-range, 1)}) and (max-width:#{nth($breakpoint-range, 2)})";
    }

    @media screen and #{$breakpoint} {
      @content;
    }

  } @else {
    @warn "No registered breakpoint for `#{$breakpoint}`";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Wazza, could you also provide the code for your 'media()' mixin? I have a guess ;)

Comment: @Kani just added it :) thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your mixin correctly, it should generate a media-query with "min" and "max" value if there's no "$is-minimum-only" or "$is-maximum-only" set. So in your case I would remove both "true" settings in this line:

```
 @include media('sm', true, true) {
```

so it looks like this

```
 @include media('sm') {
```

Now the third case inside the "@if length($breakpoint-range)" statement should take effect.

Not sure if it even makes sense to set both variables to "true". Because they have a "only" in their names, I suppose only one of them should apply at the same time ;)

I hope that helps.